# unable to get data from ElasticSearch using flutter

Tags: elasticsearch, flutter

using flutter to develop cross platform Application.i am unable to get data from elasticSearch

```
final transport = ConsoleHttpTransport(Uri.parse('http://localhost:9200/'));
  final client = elastic.Client(transport);
  final result = await client.search('indexname', '', elastic.Query.term(''),source: true);
  print(result);
```

please help me on this.

Comment: can you explain what type of search you are trying ? any link you are following, this looks like a wrong query

Comment: i am trying to fetch all the records from elastic Search and display it on flutter Table

Comment: then simply use the match_all query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html :)

Comment: when i am calling from flutter code i am not getting the result, query is working from phyton code as well kibana .

Answer (score -1):

```
_loadItems(_page) async {
    List _elements =[];

    final _transport = ConsoleHttpTransport(Uri.parse('http://test.ru:9200/'));
    final _client = elastic.Client(_transport);

    final _result = await _client.search(
      'kpmi_etalon_obj', '',
      // elastic.Query.matchAll(),
      // source: true,
      elastic.Query.term('project.code', ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009']),
      source: ['shortName','project.name','stateWork'],
      offset: _page*20,
      limit: 20
    );
    final _resultFin = _result.toMap();
    countElements = _resultFin['totalCount'];
    _elements = _resultFin['hits'];
    _elements.forEach((element) {
    final record = ElementList(
        id: element['_id'],
        title: element['doc']['project']['name'],
        subtitle: element['doc']['shortName'],
        leading: element['doc']['stateWork'],
        // trailing: element['doc']['cost'].toString()
        );
        items.add(record); 
    });
    setState(() {});
    _transport.close();
  }
```

For more example visit to https://github.com/isoos/elastic_client/tree/master/example

Comment: No result Still.

Comment: void fetchDatabasedonSearch(_page) async{ print('Elastic call ?');
  List _elements =[];

    final _transport = ConsoleHttpTransport(Uri.parse('http://localhost:9200/'));
    final _client = elastic.Client(_transport);

    final _result = await _client.search(
      'indexname', '', elastic.Query.matchAll(), source: true,
      offset: _page*20,
      limit: 20
    );
    final _resultFin = _result.toMap();
    print(_resultFin);  it is printing Elastic call after that nothing is printing.